# zip directory using java

Tags: java

I am trying to create a java program that will take in a directory path and then zip its contents. What is the best way of achieving this? Are there any packages which have this functionality already implemented?

Comment: Also a nice option is this little open source library: http://www.fuin.org/utils4j/examples/zipdir.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The package java.util.zip is available in the runtime.

Answer (score 0):

In case the interface of [java.util.zip](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/index.html?java/util/zip/package-summary.html) is too complicated, you might want to have a look at http://commons.apache.org/compress/.